# Evaluation of $\int \sec^3 (x)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, substitution

How Can I evaluate $\displaystyle \int \sec^3 (x)dx$

(Without Using **Weierstrass** Substution or Integration by parts.)

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ Let $\displaystyle I = \int\sec^3(x)dx = \int \frac{1}{\cos^3(x)}dx = \int \frac{1}{\sin ^3\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)}dx$

Now Let $\displaystyle \left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right) = t\;,$ Then $\displaystyle dx = -dt$. So $\displaystyle I = -\int \frac{1}{\sin^3 t}dt = -\int\frac{1}{2\sin^3\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)\cdot \cos^3 \left(\frac{t}{2}\right)}dt$

Now How can I solve after that

Help me

Thanks

Comment: There is an entire Wikipedia article on this integral: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_secant_cubed

Comment: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=how+to+integrate+sec+cubed

Answer (score 6):

If you don't mind partial fractions, you can simply rewrite your integral as

$$\int\frac{\cos x}{\cos^4x}dx=\int\frac{\cos x}{(1-\sin^2x)^2}dx$$

then substitute $u=\sin x$.

Comment: Anyone care to explain what's with all the downvotes?

Comment: Your method looks completely fine to me, though it is not the standard way of going about it. I would say that it is actually fairly clever in the way that it makes use of trigonometric identities.

Comment: @Mike I haven't a clue, but it's a very clever way of evaluating the given integral, rather than the standard Weierstrass substitution.

Comment: @Gahawar I can't take credit for the method.  I remember something similar from a previous topic.  It appears this whole topic got hit with a flood of downvoters.

Comment: @Gahawar: To me, this is *the* standard way of integrating odd powers of sin or cos...

Comment: @HansLundmark Certainly, I meant that one does not typically use such a method when integrating $\sec^3 x$. At least in my experience, I have seen the method used by user156227 more frequently as it requires slightly less work, though both do the job equally well.

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

Substitite

$$\sec (x)= \cosh (u) $$

$$\tan(x) = \sinh(u)$$

$$\sec^2 (x) \, \mathrm dx = \cosh (u) \,\mathrm du$$

$$\mathrm dx = \frac1{\cosh(u)}  \, \mathrm du$$

Edit: Why was this downvoted?

Here is the entire process

$$\begin{align}
\int \sec^3 x \, \mathrm dx &{}= \int \cosh^2 u\,\mathrm du \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\int ( \cosh 2u +1) \,\mathrm du \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{1}{2}\sinh2u + u\right) + C\\
&= \frac{1}{2} ( \sinh u \cosh u + u ) + C \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \sec x \tan x + \frac{1}{2} \ln|\sec x + \tan x| + C
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Your answer is correct. Upvote given! As for the downvote, it may not be obvious from inspection that $dx = \sech(u) du$. I would advise writing that it is true since $d[\sec(x)] = \tan(x)\cdot \sec(x) dx = \sinh(u)\cdot \cosh(u)\; dx$, whence... Or something along those lines.

Comment: @Chris Thanks for the advice, I have now shown some more steps.